# WebTests in VS2012 not running

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webtest

We use VS Ultimate for web tests and load tests, but since moving to VS 2012 from VS 2010, the web tests don't seem to run anymore. We used to be able to do `ctrl-r` `ctrl-t` to debug specific tests, but that doesn't work anymore. I then found out about the issue with running tests in context, so I just tried running all tests, but that didn't work either. VS2012 is acting like it doesn't see WebTest as real tests anymore.

Even when I try to view the tests in the test explorer, nothing shows up. I know my tests are correct because I can go back in to VS 2010, and everything still works like it should.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Thanks for creating this. FYI, I've raised the following suggestion to MS to improve their Web Test execution support in 2012. Feel free to vote to raise its profile.
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4272084-allow-web-performance-tests-to-be-run-from-test-ex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 dropped the "Test View" window that we used to use to run tests in VS 2010.  The new "Test Explorer" window only recognizes Unit Tests and Coded UI Tests, as you've discovered.  This totally threw me off too.

To run web and load tests (besides the obvious but tedious method of actually opening them and clicking "Run" in the editor window) you have to select the tests you want to run in the Solution Explorer, then Load Test (menu) > Run > Selected Test.  Or alternatively "All Tests in Solution".
[image: run tests from solution explorer]

You also have the option of running the individual Web Tests that are contained in any open Load Test.  Right-click on the Test Mix node (in Scenario) or any of the tests in the Test Mix.
[image: run web tests in load test]

For completeness here is the authoritative source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182541.aspx

By the way, here is another gotcha:  although you still choose testsettings for a Load Test from the Load Test menu, you now set the testsettings for Web Test execution *separately*, under the Test menu:
[image: set testsettings for web test]

Comment: Thanks, I hope whoever came up with this solution at MS is fired.

Comment: @Zipper, I have a sinking feeling that MS has lost interest in the Web & Load test feature (e.g. scant improvements in VS2012).  I really hope I'm wrong.